# Button's style Android

Tags: java, android, xml, button, styles

Who can help me with style button? How I must change button's style, that I haven't problems with angles, I mean, Why I have default style of button. 
this is my code and display problem

[Angels1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTwsG.png)

[Angles2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5s9w.png)

```
Button style="@style/gradient_button"
```

style - gradient_button

```
<style name="button_common">
 <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
 <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
    <style name="gradient_button" parent="@style/button_common">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_grad</item>
    </style>
```

and file button_grad

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/b59" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/y59" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/b59" />
</selector>
```

b59 and y59 these are image with 9-patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your angle's problem the error is about your images or about 9-patch.

You can write the style for button in your drawable folder:

*style_button.xml*
:

```
<style name="button_common">
 <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
 <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

*selector.xml* in your drawable folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/b59" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/y59" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/b59" />
</selector>
```

Apply that style to your button :

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                style="@style/style_button"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/selector"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:text="btnText" />
```

Comment: I tried, but still there was a problem with angels. Can you see on picture 1 and 2, I don't know. Maybe it's problem background default button(Material design)

Comment: maybe the problem is about your image and about 9-patch

Comment: Oh, I think, You are sure. Thanks you

Comment: I find, what it is problem. I must write in Button line android:outlineProvider=none. Maybe somebody will need